# Unable to run jsfiddle code on browser

Tags: javascript, mootools

Does anyone know how I can see the result of : http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/KGxHF/ in my brwoser. I want to use the code but no result is shown.  What frame works and extension should I add? What is Mootool 1.4.5 that is added on the left section of Jsfiddle?

```css
 Mootool 1.4.5
```

Thanks

Comment: Mootools is a javascript library/framework. Do you mean you want that effect in a page you have? or that the jsfiddle does not work on your browser?

Comment: oh ok. Thanks for replying. but how can I add Mootools library. For example if I want to add D3.js I write: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> but what should I write for Mootools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the script library in your page to run Mootools. MooTools is a Object-Oriented JavaScript framework/library.

For example, insert this in the `<head>` tag, before other `.js` files that need Mootools:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mootools.net/download/get/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat.js"></script>
```

Look [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7My3/) for the same demo but with Mootools loaded by the link i wrote above. The better though is to download the link and run the .js file from your server/computer.

To run it in a page of yours you can use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mootools.net/download/get/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<style>
path { stroke: #000; fill: brown; stroke-width: .5px }
circle { fill: red; }
</style>
<script>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var SPACING = 5;

    var data = d3.range(50).map(function(d, i) {
        return {x: i * SPACING, y: (Math.random()*100)};
    });
    var h = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; }) + 15;

    /* Create the lookup table */
    var table = [];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        table[d.x] = d.y;
    });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 410)
        .attr("height", 125)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(5, 5)");

    var area = svg.selectAll("path").data([data]).enter().append("path")
        .attr(
            "d",
            d3.svg.area()
                .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                .y0(h)        
                .y1(function(d) { return d.y; })
        );

    var circle = svg.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("display", "none");

    area
        .on("mouseover", function() { circle.attr("display", "block"); })
        .on("mousemove", update)
        .on("mouseout", function() { circle.attr("display", "none"); });

    function update() {    
        var x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
        var y;

        if ( table[x] === undefined ) {
            var lower = x - (x % SPACING);
            var upper = lower + SPACING;
            var between = d3.interpolateNumber(table[lower], table[upper]);
            y = between( (x % SPACING) / SPACING );
        } else {
            y = table[x];
        }

        circle
            .attr("cx", x)
            .attr("cy", y);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) it was helful but it still does not show anything. Do you think I should add more libraries?

Comment: @sasha, you mean you have a page were you try to have that code running? Or you cannot see the fiddle working? Mootools script should run before other scripts if you are adding it in your page.

Comment: I have http server and I want to see it run on my browser. When I make a html file with this code and add the library that you sent, nothing shows on my browser. I can see the resulf on Jsfiddle but how can I use the code myself?

Comment: Wrap your code with this: `window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // your code
});` - I will update my answer also

Comment: @sasha, Wrap your code with this: `window.addEvent('domready', function() { // your code });` so your code runs when the page finished loading. - I updated my answer also with a full page code, make a page with just that code and it should work, I just tested it.

Comment: It was great! Thank you indeed for your help :)